# I am trying to update 12.04 to 13.04 but I get a message saying "Saving installed packages..."

Tags: 12.04, 12.10, upgrade

The dots go round and round but after a few hours of this I have to kill the process.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Try to update 12.04 first then do release upgrade.

Comment: @Danatela you meant 12.10, no?

Comment: Could you add a screenshot or more details about it?

Comment: @Danatela did you really think that? Check again the [release page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) and confirm. Either way, only from LTS release to LTS release you can skip upgrades, with normal releases **you can not**.

Comment: @Braiam, oops, OK :) Raring will be out of date even more shortly then Quantal, so strange...

Comment: Try `sudo do-release-upgrade -d`

Answer (score 0):

Open the terminal and try:

1. `sudo su`. Enter password for account.
2. `apt-get update`.
3. `apt-get upgrade`.
4. `apt-get dist-upgrade`

Comment: Thanks Metrik, I tried that, 1. worked;  2. worked 3. started but wanted me to put 13.04 CD in the drive & press enter.  That didn't help (I made the CD by burning the ISO file to DVD.  I also got a pop-up window telling me it was waiting for apt-get to end.  Maybe I should just blatt 12.04 and start clean?

Comment: Sorry could I not help.

Comment: After u re-install try using this guide to upgrade. http://askubuntu.com/questions/110477/how-do-i-upgrade-to-a-newer-version-of-ubuntu.  Old version. But should show u a good way to go about it.